# Codeigniter - If user is already logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wanting to know how I can check if a user is logged in, but then if someone else with the same login creditionals tries to login send them a message to say the user is already logged in somewhere else.

So for example:

Pete - Logs in with pete as the username and pete1 as the password, but pete gave his details to a friend to use and his friend Dave tries to loin with the same details at the same time, it needs to send Dave a message saying someone is already logged in with those details.

How can this be done please.

I already have a is_logged_in function that check the user is logged in.

Comment: How would you know if the user hasn't changed computers right quick? Since we're talking websites you never keep an ongoing connection, but instead "Request -> Response". What you **could** do is keep polling the server when you're logged in, and then say "if users last poll was less than 30 seconds ago they're definitely logged in".

Comment: It's not me that's wants this function but my client and maybe I should go back to them and explain it's not really worth doing based on your explanation. Thanks h2oooooo

Comment: You can also explain your client that this would do the following: 1) It would generate a lot more traffic because you had to keep polling 2) it would not be accurate (what if their computer froze or your server didn't respond within 30 seconds) 3) If your client says "they need to log out" then consider someone rebooting their computer, deleting their cookies etc. - how long would it take to expire? The user would not be able to log in during that time even on the same computer.

Comment: Yes I thought about that too, good point thanks again for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You need a "user sessions" model to record logged in users,

on user log in, check if session exists in "user sessions", if yes send message of "already logged in"

then establish session on user side,
then add session to your model

on logout, 
destroy session from user side and from the "user sessions" model

---

This will allow same user to login from multi devices, with notifying them.
however this might bring you up to the problem of having a "home device" which he usually logs in from, so that you don't spam him with "already logged in" messages

Answer (score 1):

I did something very close to this a few years ago however i approached with a little differently. Basically I only allowed one 1 login per user and any subsequent login would result in the other users session being destroyed.

To get it to work this way I had to create a custom session manager to store the users username with the session ID in the DB. Then all i did was do a lookup to see if the user was already logged in, if they was then i just removed the DB session.

Your solution could easily be achieved by doing the same but changing the logic a little and just preventing the user getting past the lookup part.

All you have to do is extend the CodeIgniter session class and make your changes, its really not that difficult either.

Comment: Do you have any examples so i can see how you achieved it?

Answer (score 0):

Logging your sessions to the database will allow you to track this. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Search for "Saving Session Data to a Database" on the page.

Once sessions are stored in the database, you can check if that username is currently logged in. It does come with a caveat though - if the user does not log out before closing the browser, and the session is not set to expire properly, it will tell you the user is already logged in, even if he/she is not (based on whether the session data exists).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by checking cookies and setting a specific cookie for the user. If a user's session cookie does not match the system's session cookie, they that user is forced out and the new user takes control. This can be annoying though.